# Selecting an email template and BCC address based on the message type

Tags: php

My code-editor "show hints" says that the method length exceeds 20 lines.  How can I refactor the `setEmailTemplateBcc` function?

```
private function setBcc($bcc)
    {
        if ($bcc) {
            $this->bcc = explode(',', $bcc);
        }
    }


    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->setEmailTemplateBcc($type);
        return $this;
    }

    private function setEmailTemplateBcc($type)
    {
        $template = '';
        $bcc = '';

        switch ($type) {
            case self::EMAIL_NEW_SUBSCRIPTION:
                $template = DataHelper::XML_PATH_SUBSCRIPTION_EMAIL;
                $bcc = DataHelper::XML_PATH_REMINDER_EMAIL_BCC;
                break;
            case self::EMAIL_CARD_ADD:
                $template = DataHelper::XML_PATH_NEW_CARD_ADD_EMAIL;
                $bcc = DataHelper::XML_PATH_NEW_CARD_ADD_EMAIL_BCC;
                break;
            case self::EMAIL_PAYMENT_FAILED:
                $template = DataHelper::XML_PATH_PAYMENT_FAILED_EMAIL;
                $bcc = DataHelper::XML_PATH_PAYMENT_FAILED_EMAIL_BCC;
                break;
            case self::EMAIL_PROFILE_UPADATE:
                $template = DataHelper::XML_PATH_PROFILE_UPDATE_EMAIL;
                $bcc = DataHelper::XML_PATH_PROFILE_UPDATE_EMAIL_BCC;
                break;
            case self::EMAIL_REMINDER:
                $template = DataHelper::XML_PATH_REMINDER_EMAIL;
                $bcc = DataHelper::XML_PATH_REMINDER_EMAIL_BCC;
                break;
            case self::EMAIL_TOPUP_REMINDER:
                $template = DataHelper::XML_PATH_EWALLET_TOPUP_REMINDER_EMAIL;
                $bcc = DataHelper::XML_PATH_EWALLET_TOPUP_REMINDER_EMAIL;
                break;
        }

        $this->setTemplate($template);
        $this->setBcc($bcc);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create two new static variables in your class, arrays that contain all options, like

```
public static $template = [
    self::EMAIL_NEW_SUBSCRIPTION => DataHelper::XML_PATH_SUBSCRIPTION_EMAIL,
    self::EMAIL_CARD_ADD         => DataHelper::XML_PATH_NEW_CARD_ADD_EMAIL_BCC,
    // and so on
];
```

then setting the email template will be as simple as just one line:

```
$template = self::$template[self::EMAIL_CARD_ADD] ?? '';
```

and the same goes for BCC

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this approach.

```
interface EmailTemplateInterface
{
    public function create($type);

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports($type);
}

class EmailNewSubscription implements EmailTemplateInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function create($type)
    {
        echo 'XML_PATH_SUBSCRIPTION_EMAIL';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function supports($type)
    {
        return $type === 'XML_PATH_SUBSCRIPTION_EMAIL';
    }
}

class EmailCardAdd implements EmailTemplateInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function create($type)
    {
        echo 'EMAIL_CARD_ADD';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function supports($type)
    {
        return $type === 'EMAIL_CARD_ADD';
    }
}

class BuildEmailTemplate implements EmailTemplateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EmailTemplateInterface[]
     */
    private $emailTemplateInterface;

    /**
     * @param EmailTemplateInterface[] $emailCreators
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct(array $emailCreators)
    {
        foreach ($emailCreators as $builder) {
            if (!$builder instanceof EmailTemplateInterface) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('emailCreator is not valid');
            }
        }
        $this->emailTemplateInterface = $emailCreators;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function create($type)
    {
        foreach ($this->emailTemplateInterface as $builder) {
            if ($builder->supports($type)) {
                return $builder->create($type);
            }
        }

        throw new \UnexpectedValueException('email creator for supporting this type is not found');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function supports($type)
    {
        foreach ($this->emailTemplateInterface as $builder) {
            if ($builder->supports($type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
// usage
$emailCreators = [
    new EmailNewSubscription(),
    new EmailCardAdd(),
];

$delegate = new BuildEmailTemplate($emailCreators);

$delegate->create('XML_PATH_SUBSCRIPTION_EMAIL');
```